# A Microservice with Asynchronous REST Calls

Tags: rest, asynchronous, web

I wish to implement a web api call - a Controller method - that takes a user id and sends out notifications for one or more devices related to that user.

In the Service module, this call will perform 1 asynchronous operation per eligible device.

Because the service operations are asynchronous, there are 2 basic options:

1. I could return a result to the client immediately and allow it to reconnect for the status of the notifications.
2. I could wait until all of the asynchronous operations are complete before returning.

Which it considered "best practice"; the former or the latter? I'd appreciate hearing some experienced feedback.

So far, I've read competing opinions on this:
[DANIEL WESTHEIDE](https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/why-restful-communication-between-microservices-can-be-perfectly-fine/) argues that while some experts consider it an anti-pattern (monolithic) to have synchronous REST calls in a Microservice, it's only inter-service communication that **should** be asynchronous.

Comment: FYI, opinion based questions are against the stack overflow rules. There's cases where this rule is applied too strictly, but I think this is not really one of them. There's a good chance this question will get closed with this reason.

Comment: I don't think it's a good rule, but this is just a heads up. Don't be discouraged in finding an answer, but maybe look in a few different spots.